# IE capabilities with Jenkins

Tags: ruby, selenium, jenkins, selenium-grid2

I have installed:

- selenium grid 2.53.0 hub +node for IE;
- Jenkins;
- IE 11.

When I try to run a build for IE via batch command with variable BROWSER=ie I'm getting next error:

```
Error forwarding the new session cannot find : Capabilities [{browserName=internetexplorer, version=null}] (org.openqa.grid.common.exception.GridException) (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError)
```

What can be wrong? Because when I run my tests not via grid everything is ok.
If I connect node for *chrome* and specify *chrome* everything is ok too.

Comment: There are a lot of things that are still missing here. How does your RemoteWebDriver instantiation look like. Please show us that code. You state that you pass the browser flavor as "ie" in your batch, but the error states that the browser name passed to it was "internetexplorer". You need to ensure that the browsername you are passing is "internet explorer" because that is the only value that the grid understands.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DesiredCapabilities cap = null;
WebDriver driver = null;
cap = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
cap.setBrowserName("internet explorer");
cap.setPlatform(Platform.WIN8); //specify the platform
driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(nodeURL), cap);
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this.
I specified incorrectly BROWSER value in Jenkins. Must be BROWSER="internet explorer"